# Check if String ends with two digits after a dot in Regular Expression?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to test if a String ends with EXACTLY two digits after a dot in Java using a Regular Expression. How can achieve this?

Something like "500.23" should return true, while "50.3" or "50" should return false.

I tried things like `"500.00".matches("/^[0-9]{2}$/")` but it returns false.

Comment: try this: `str.matches(".*\\.\\d\\d")` (not worth dignifying this question with an answer, but this may stop everyone wasting their time)

Comment: Something like `.*\d{3}\.\d{2}$`

Comment: This seems very simple. You must have tried something by now.

Comment: @Bohemian Shouldn't you have `$` there? Otherwise it'll match `3.23A`?

Comment: @MarounMaroun Not for `matches`. But a `*?` instead of `*` would be good practice.

Comment: I tries things like `"500.00".matches("/^[0-9]{2}$/")` but it returns false

Comment: @MarounMaroun no. `matches()` must must the *whole* string, so `^` and `$` are *implied*. Alas, I tried to save ppl time, but look what's happened...

Comment: @Bohemian lol.. now where's your scary regexes that you always show to newbies?..

Comment: Now that OP has posted an attempt, we can proceed. Muhahaha!

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks bohemian, that's the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a RegEx that might help you:

```
^\d+\.\d{2,2}$
```

it may  neither be perfect nor the most efficient, but it should lead you in the right direction.

**`^`** says that the expression should start here
 **`\d`** looks for any digit
 **`+`** says, that the leading \d can appear as often as necessary (1–infinity)
 **`\.`** means you are expecting a dot(.) at one point
 **`\d{2,2}`** thats the trick: it says you want 2 and exactly 2 digits (not less not more)
 **`$`** tells you that the expression ends there (after the 2 digits)

in Java the \ needs to be escaped so it would be:

```
^\\d*\\.\\d{2,2}$
```

**Edit**
if you don't need digits before the dot (`.`) or if you really don't care what comes before the dot, then you can replace the first `\d+` by a `.*` as in Bohemians answer. The (non escaped) dot means that the expression can contain any character (not only digets). Then even the leading `^` might no longer be necessary.

```
 \\.*\\.\\d{2,2}$
```

Comment: `\d*` would also match zero digits; and i guess you could make the regex a bit more cryptical/shorter by just using `\d{2}`

Comment: @GyroGearless good point, thanks. I replaced the * by  + . Concerning the {2} that's of course shorter, but when one doesn't use RegEx very often (like me) the {min,max} notation is easier to understand:)

Comment: OP does not say the input must be only digits, so `ABC.12` should pass too

Comment: and another good point :) Thanks @Bohemian, that was a just an assumption from my part

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit. In fact i'm working just with numbers, I have the control in another part of code, so I shouldn't have to check it. So both GameDroids and Bohemian answers are really perfect for me. I don't know which to choose. I think i'll go with GameDroids because its explanation, but both are really perfect for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use this `regex`

```
 String s="987234.42";
    if(Pattern.matches("^\\d+(\\.\\d{2})$", s)){   // string must start with digit followed by .(dot) then exactly two digit.
    ....
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, forward slashes are no part of regular expressions whatsoever. They are however used by some languages to *delimit* regular expressions - but not java, so don't use them.

Secondly, in java `matches()` must match the *whole* string to return true (so `^` and `$` are implied in the regex).

Try this:

```
if (str.matches(".*\\.\\d\\d"))
    // it ends with dot then 2 digits
```

Note that in java a bash slash in a regex requires escaping by a further back slash in a string literal.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian. Please read my comment in the other answer. Thanks